# Does there exist a 'curly' multiplication symbol?

Tags: symbols, math-operators

> *Question*: Does there exist a 'curly' multiplication symbol?

For example, for 'curly' equal sign, we have `$\approx,$` which distinguishes itself from the normal `$=$` sign. 
I would like to do the same for `$\times$` operator.

Comment: So you basically want two `\sim` (one orthogonal to the other)?

Comment: What kind of operator should it be? I mean, what mean should it have?

Comment: @TeXnician Yes,you are right.

Comment: @TeXnician - I tried your suggestion of using two rotated `\sim` symbols (1 rotated +45 degrees, the other rotated -45 degrees), but the result looks horribly like a swastika, so I won't post an answer here.

Comment: @Mico Same result here ;)

Comment: @Idonknow - What you call a "curly multiplication symbol that sort of looks like `\times`" will almost certainly look suspiciously like a swastika. If you somehow manage to create such a symbol (I, for one, am *not* going to show you how to construct this symbol in LaTeX!), I can virtually guarantee that all readers of your document will come to a dead stop when their eyes first reach this symbol. They may well forget everything else you wrote; all they'll remember it by is "the paper with the swastika symbol(s)". Do you really want to incur the risk of creating such an impression?

Comment: this doesn't appear in unicode (as others have observed).  if you can find a published instance of the symbol, i am in a position to submit it to unicode, but published documentation is required.  (they need context and a meaning, to give it a reasonable name.)

Answer (score 3):

This one might do the trick, and it doesn't look like a swastika. You could turn it into an operator. Unicode Tifinagh alphabet block ahaggar yazh at Unicode 11595, hex 2D4B, .[image: ahaggar yazh]

Answer (score 1):

If it isn't [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_operators_and_symbols_in_Unicode) I think that is very unlikely that exist any symbol like that in LaTeX. I tried on [shapecatcher](http://shapecatcher.com/) but without results. In this case, if you really want it, you should create it by yourself.

Comment: The question isn't about creating the symbol but only about its existence. I cannot be sure it doesn't exist but it's very likely since there is no Unicode character with that shape and no symbol in shapecatcher database. If, after my comment, you still think that my answer is inappropriate I will remove it.  You're a far better user than me and I trust your opinion.

Comment: Sorry, your interpretation of the question is totally correct, it just does not seem to be that common on TeX.SX. I'll remove my previous comment.